# Deleted hard drive results in Windows recovery screen

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, recovery

I have a late 2014 Mac Mini. I did go into recovery mode (Option + r) and did delete the hard drive.
Then I screwed up and restartet the Mac Mini instead of going back to the list from Option+r menu at the startup.

Current Issue:

Now if I start my Mac Mini, I get a Windows recovery screen which tells me add a bootable device. 
I can read "Your PC needs to be repaired", a error code 0xc0000225 and enter to try again or press F8 for startup settings. I had bootcamp installed.

I tried:

- That reset NVRAM with option+alt+r+p (Now startup sound is louder then before this reset)
- Holding option+r to get into Mac recovery but not working
- Holding t for hard drive menu but not showing

No command for startup worked. I get the windows recovery screen always. I don't need any recovery of my files. I just want to have a clean MacOS installation.

Do I need to install Windows with a bootable windows image or is there any other way to install MacOS again?

Mac Mini late 2014 - 
MacOS 10.14 (no idea which sub number) was installed

Comment: Recovery is Cmd/R or Cmd/Opt/R for Internet Recovery [though it should automatically try the second if the first doesn't work].

Comment: @Tetsujin Didn't know about Cmd/Opt/R. That worked. Thank you very much. Sometimes it's just a small stupid thing. Problem solved.

Comment: Please don‘t include the answer in the question. Post it below or flag the question for deletion instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access Internet Recovery with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, and reinstall macOS from there.